# Ionic on iPhone How to Set StatusBar Transparent

Tags: iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, statusbar

Hi I'm creating an app based on ionic.

I want to set my StatusBar transparent like this
[image]

But I've tried any of codes, it always goes 
[image]

Here is my `app.js` settings

```
    if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
        StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
```

How can I make it right like the first picture goes?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @dwinnbrown Not yet. You stuck in the same embarrassment? Please help! The app shows like the second picture goes although the code is right. The background of status bar doesn't become what I want.

Comment: I found that this was just a bug with the Ionic viewer app. When I actually ran it on my device, it didn't do it

Comment: @dwinnbrown Thank you bro, that is what I guess! Because the same setting gets different result between Simulator and Ionic Viewer. Result of Simulator is correct but Ionic Viewer app covered with the white color as you see the second picture.

Comment: Yeah I found that exactly and after more research found others to have had this issue. I did raise it with the developer of the ionic viewer app and that did respond so they should be aware of it now. I just ignored it for now, knowing that it's working fine when I run on simulator or device.

Comment: @dwinnbrown Glad to heard that. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem - it's something which I'm sure will be sorted at some point but just probably isn't highest on their list of priorities

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to explicitly set the background color, like so

```
if (window.StatusBar) {
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
    StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#14c1f3');
}
```

See also http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/status-bar/

Comment: I changed my code this way, but it still seems like the second picture. Is that the question about Ionic View App not my own?  Or just setting wrong?  Q_Q

Comment: Can remember having similar issue with a regular Xcode project. Set the status bar style there to Default.But in my case I was using dark text in the Navbar, so might not resolve your issue.

Comment: Found similar issue here, https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-cant-change-color-of-ios-statusbar/49135. There the solution was to set StatusBar.overlaysWebView to false. Don't have a proper dev env now, so can't test this out for you.